# How can I control two lights with the same switch and one of them individually?

Tags: lighting, switch, circuit

I have two bulbs, say *bulb 1* and *bulb 2*, also two switches, say *switch 1* and *switch 2*.

I want the wiring to be such that when *switch 1* is turned, both bulbs light up but when *switch 2* is turned, only *bulb 2* will light up.

#### Why I need this?

There is an area, from where after returning people forget to turn off bulb. Another bulb when lit up on the way is good way to remind them to turn off light. The bulb on the way should work independently but the bulb in the area should be dependent.

#### What I can do

I am ready to make circuits(with components) if they aren't commercially available. Also, advanced options like sensors or remote controls, I don't want to use.

Comment: If switch 1 turns on bulb 2, do you want is wiring so that switch 2 can't turn off bulb 2, it would have to be turned off by switch 1?

Comment: A simple, dumb motion sensor seems like a _much_ simpler answer. Doesn't require any sort of home automation, internet access or anything else. When it detects motion, it turns on. When it no longer detects motion (for a built-in switch defined amount of time), it turns off.

Comment: Is neutral available at the switch box?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/49223/18078

Comment: If I have this straight, you want Light 1 to be solely controlled by Switch1 (switch2 has no effect on it) and Light2 should always be on if Switch1 is on or Switch2 is on (only off if both are off)? If so, then Switch1 directly controls Light1 and Switch1 and Switch2 are in an 'OR' configuration with Light2.

Comment: If my previous comment is correct, then you can easily wire this up with the only special equipment needed being a double pole switch (as opposed to a typical single pole) for Switch1.

Comment: Why not tie the bulbs together and use 3-way switches? You'll have the switch available in both places to allow light to be turned on, and when you turn off the "obvious" light, the "hidden" light is also taken care of

Comment: Also, have you considered a switch with a pilot light on it that's set up so the pilot light is on when the light's on?

Comment: @GlenYates your solution may be same as in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/257997/157375). If this is so, thanks for your help.

Comment: @FreeMan Noted you suggestion as alternative. Would definitely try if this method doesn't prove useful. Thanks

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The reason people forget to switch off light is that it's in very corner behind the doors. So, pilot light isn't useful in this case.

Comment: @GlenYates' [suggestion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257953/how-can-i-control-two-lights-with-the-same-switch-and-one-of-them-individually?noredirect=1#comment519783_257953) (which should be an answer) is _similar to_ but _distinctly different_ from [Jasen's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/257997/34147) which is wrong for precisely the reason I noted in a comment on it (before I'd read Glen's comment above).

Comment: Smart switches are the answer. Just set the parameters of each switch and walla bing walla bang you have your needs met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This digram shows the electrical connections you need

how you convert that into wires depends on your circumstances

[image]

Comment: -1. I don't see how this resolves the OP's problem, despite his checkmark. In the _current_ switch config, `SW1` controls both lights (off). However, throw `SW2`, and `L2` turns on, `SW1` has zero control over that. `SW1` open or closed has _no_ control if `SW2` is connected pin 2 to pin 3. If `SW1` were a double-pole, double-throw switch on both the red & black lines, _then_ it would control both, turning `L2` on/off based on the position of `SW2`, but this won't work as is.

Comment: @FreeMan I think this answer solves the purpose. If pin 2 to 3 is connected of `SW2`, it will make `L2` independent of `SW1`, that's what I mentioned in the question. Putting it more simple there should be no way to turn `L1` on and `L2` as off. With `SW1` as double pole double throw, this would not work.

Comment: +1 This diagram exactly matches the description in my answer.

Comment: @FreeMan: I don't think it resolves the OP's problem either -- *but it satisfies his specification*.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri This does not match the description in your answer. If SW1 is ON and SW2 is ON (i.e. in the up position) then L1 will be OFF, which does not match the logic in your diagram. My answer however fully supports the boolean logic shown in your diagram.

Comment: @Glen Yates: Look again please. If SW1 is ON then mains voltage is applied to the red wires. L1 is connected between the red and gray wires. Current is returned from L1 via the gray wires to mains neutral.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Umm, yeah, you are absolutely right, total brain fart on my end.

Comment: Glen Yates: Yeah, that's why your circuit is better than this one -- yours radiates fewer Bf/Wh.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of the querent's requirements:

```
Switch 1    Switch 2    Bulb 1      Bulb 2
-----       -----       -----       -----
 Off         Off         Dark        Dark
 Off         ON          Dark        LIT
 ON          Off         LIT         LIT
 ON          ON          LIT         LIT
```

This can be wired with some of the same equipment used for a "three-way" circuit.

In the following I assume power arrives at switch 1. I also refer to the "line" and "load" terminals on a simple switch -- these are not marked, just choose.

Run a 14/3 (or similar) cable between the switch boxes. I assume the colors are white, black, red.

At switch 1 connect the service neutral to the neutral wire to bulb 1 AND to the white wire in the 14/3 cable. Install a simple ("two-way") switch. Connect the service hot to the "line" terminal on the switch AND to the black wire of the 14/3 cable. Connect the "load" terminal on the switch to the hot wire to bulb 1 AND to the red wire in the 14/3 cable.

At switch 2 connect the white wire in the 14/3 cable to the neutral wire to bulb 2. Install a "three-way" (single-pole double-throw) switch. Connect the common terminal on the switch to the hot wire to bulb 2. Connect one traveler terminal on the switch to the black wire in the 14/3 cable. Connect the other traveler terminal on the switch to the red wire in the 14/3 cable.

Comment: A drawing would go a long way toward helping with understanding your answer.

Comment: I'd hesitiate to suggest a wiring gauge until I knew what size breaker the circuit was to be connected to.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what I was envisioning, please excuse my PowerPoint drawing skills. This will implement the logic expressed in my comments to OP and as laid out in the table in the answer by A. I. Breveleri.

Switch 1 is a double-pole switch (not a 3-way) and Switch 2 is a regular single pole. Assuming a 15 amp circuit, all the cables are 14/2 except the cable which goes between the junction boxes which is 14/3.

*Note: Ground wires are not shown for clarity.*
[image: 2 Switches 2 LIghts]

Comment: This is what I do now that Reddit sucks. This is definitely more interesting so no regrets. Your drawing skills are on point.